# What are successful ways to archive for public consumption abandoned WordPress installs?

Tags: html, wordpress

We have a significant number of Wordpress installs that have been in operation for a number of years and have not been in use for about 18 months or so.  We have been keeping up with WP updates and the like, but it's a pain to have to update each blog each time and they are constantly being probed by spammers and hackers.

However we still get significant traffic from these installs, so we don't like to take them down.

What I would like to do is convert them to static pages, dump, backup and drop the DB's and delete all of the php code.  Closing the potential security holes, but allowing users to still find the pages.

Has anyone out there done this before and what were the issues you found?

Comment: I found these wp plugins http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-static/faq/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/ which may be of some use.

Comment: There's also many WP -> static blogging system exporters like [WordPress to Jeckyl](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/blog-migrations)

Answer (score 1):

There are wordpress plugins that simplify updating multiple WP installs. [WPRemote](https://wpremote.com/) is a favorite, but there is also [ManageWP](https://managewp.com/) and [InfiniteWP](http://infinitewp.com/).